# Custom API integration with WordPress

Tags: api, webautomation, wordpress-json-api, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-4.3

I'm planning on creating a deals and coupon site using wordpress. I want to automate it with the the data api that gives data in JSON. But how will I integrate this api in compatibility with WordPress to create new post that contain custom fields for each offer.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has both coupon management and an API. I suggest you start there...